# Including delimiters in output tokens with std::sregex_token_iterator C++ (no Boost)

Tags: c++, token, delimiter, interpreter, lexer

I'm attempting to tokenize a scripting language in C++ and am struggling currently with including further delimiters as tokens.

```
#ifndef TOKENIZER_H
#define TOKENIZER_H

#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

regex re("[\\s]+");

vector<string> deconstructDelimit(const string &input) {
    string trimmed = input.substr(input.find_first_not_of(" \t\f\v\n\r"));

    vector<string> decons;
    sregex_token_iterator it(trimmed.begin(), trimmed.end(), re, -1);
    sregex_token_iterator reg_end;
    for (; it != reg_end; ++it) {
        decons.push_back(it->str());
    }
    return decons;
}

vector<string> tokenize(const string &input) {
    vector<string> whitespace;

    string currToken;
    for (auto it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); ++it) {
        if (*it == '\'') {
            if (currToken.length()) {
                vector<string> decons = deconstructDelimit(currToken);
                whitespace.insert(whitespace.end(), decons.begin(), decons.end());
                currToken.clear();
            }

            whitespace.push_back("\'");
            ++it;

            while (*it != '\'' && it != input.end()) {
                currToken += *it;
                ++it;
            }

            if (currToken.length()) whitespace.push_back(currToken);
            whitespace.push_back("\'");
            currToken.clear();
        } else if (*it == '\"') {
            if (currToken.length()) {
                vector<string> decons = deconstructDelimit(currToken);
                whitespace.insert(whitespace.end(), decons.begin(), decons.end());
                currToken.clear();
            }

            whitespace.push_back("\"");
            ++it;

            while (*it != '\"' && it != input.end()) {
                currToken += *it;
                ++it;
            }

            if (currToken.length()) whitespace.push_back(currToken);
            whitespace.push_back("\"");
            currToken.clear();
        } else {
            currToken += *it;
        }
    }

    if (currToken.length()) {
        vector<string> decons = deconstructDelimit(currToken);
        whitespace.insert(whitespace.end(), decons.begin(), decons.end());
    }

    return whitespace;
}


#endif
```

So far, it is able to convert this code:

```
i = 1
while(i <= 10) {
    print i + " " then i++
}
```

into these tokens:

```
i
=
1
while(i
<=
10)
{
print
i
+
"

"
then
i++
}
```

However, I want to then split this string vector of tokens by other delimiters, such as operators (++, =, <=, +, etc.), keywords (while, then, etc.), and other grammar like parentheses and brackets, preferably without using boost. What would be the best way for me to achieve this, given the string vector output of my current progress?

**Edit:**

For example, the result of further tokenization would be:

```
i
=
1
while(i   ->   while, (, i
<=
10)   ->   10, )
{
print
i
+
"

"
then
i++   ->   i, ++
}
```

Which, expanded, would be:

```
i
=
1
while
(
i
<=
10
)
{
print
i
+
"

"
then
i
++
}
```

Comment: Not sure if regex is the way to go.  You might need a real parser.  You could check out [`boost::spirit::qi`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi.html)

Comment: The problem with string splitting is you need a way to determine *where* to split. It might be that you'll have to iterate through the contents of each string and detect the operators you mention and use their position to break the strings into smaller parts.

Comment: @JoelTrauger That was my fear. It seems like an awful blow to time complexity to make this step of lexing be O(n * m), where n is the number of tokens after whitespace splitting, and m is the number of symbols to split on

Comment: Normal string splitting happens in O(n) time anyway where n is the length of the string. Since every character of the string is compared to the delimiter, you can just overload the splitting function or add to it so that it properly breaks off your operators as well. Just a thought.

Comment: I find it odd that you're rewriting the string tokenization function `strtok()` that is included in C (which you can embed in c++ with use of headers). Check out this [xstrtok function](http://svn.kesteb.us/repos/cclibs/misc/xstrtok.c) which is a modification of the original function to see how it might benefit you in your string splitting. I've never tokenized a whole file before so it could be adapted for that.

Comment: @JoelTrauger I guess I was hesitant to use strtok() because I've heard bad things about it from other people. I'll look into xstrtok though, and see if it'll fit my needs. Thanks!

Comment: I'm also thinking about maybe implementing some kind of additional tokenization using a "candidate system", in which, every time a character is found after a previous token ended, the function finds the tokens that match so far, and continue until the correct token is found and the token ends

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you when I tried to separate items of a math expression using a regex. I successfully found a well working way to do it :

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> resplit(const std::string& s, std::string rg_str = "\\s+"){
    std::cmatch cm;
    std::string reg_str = std::string("(.*?)(")+rg_str+std::string(")");
    std::string str = s+std::string(" ");
    unsigned a = 0;
    unsigned b = 1;
    std::string subs = str.substr(a, b-a);
    std::vector<std::string> elements;
    while(b <= str.length()){
        subs = str.substr(a, b-a);
        if(std::regex_match(subs.c_str(), cm, std::regex(reg_str), std::regex_constants::match_default)){
            for(unsigned i=1; i<cm.size(); i++){
                std::string cmi(cm[i]);

                // The following part can be adapted if you want to include whitespaces or empty strings
                if(!std::regex_match(cmi.c_str(), std::regex("\\s*"))){
                    elements.push_back(std::string(cm[i]));
                }
            }
            a = b;
            b = b+1;
        } else {
            b++;
        }
    }
    return elements;
}
```

When I use it on `resplit("sin(x^2) + 1", "[^0-9a-zPI.]|[ \\(\\)]");`, I get : `["sin", "(", "x", "^", "2", ")", "+", "1"]`.

Don't forget to change :

```cpp
 if(!std::regex_match(cmi.c_str(), std::regex("\\s*"))){
     elements.push_back(std::string(cm[i]));
 }
```

into :

```cpp
 if(!std::regex_match(cmi.c_str(), std::regex(""))){
     elements.push_back(std::string(cm[i]));
 }
```

if you want to include spaces (it will remove empty strings though, but this is preferable).
I hope it's useful to someone. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is my complete solution which consists of few helper functions:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void ltrim(std::string& str) {
    str.erase(str.begin(), std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](int character) {
        return !std::isspace(character);
    }));
}

void rtrim(std::string& str) {
    str.erase(std::find_if(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), [](int character) {
        return !std::isspace(character);
    }).base(), str.end());
}

void trim(std::string& str) {
    ltrim(str);
    rtrim(str);
}

bool is_empty(std::string const& str) {
    return str.empty() || str.find_first_not_of(' ') == std::string::npos;
}

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string const& str, std::string const& pattern) {
    std::regex regex(pattern);

    std::vector<std::string> result(
        std::sregex_token_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), regex, {-1, 0}),
        std::sregex_token_iterator()
    );

    for (auto& token : result) {
        trim(token);
    }

    result.erase(
        std::remove_if(
            result.begin(),
            result.end(),
            [](std::string const& str) { return is_empty(str); }
        ),
        result.end()
    );

    return result;
}

int main() {
    for (auto &s: split("sin(x^2) + 1", "[^0-9a-zPI.]|[ \\(\\)]")) {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The key thing I used is `std::sregex_token_iterator`. As the last argument to its constructor I passed `{-1, 0}` where `-1` represents the parts that are not matched and `0` represents the entire match.

The result of the above code snippet is:

```
sin
(
x
^
2
)
+
1
```